# In a shell script, how to get current directory of ruby gem executables?

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems, zsh

On macOS, I want to make my `.zshrc` automatically add current location of ruby gem executables to the $PATH variable.

Currently I just do:

```
if [ -d "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin" ]; then
    export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

But that is not very future-proof, is it? E.g., on my next macOS installation, the version of Ruby might be different.

I know, that one can get the correct directory with:

```
$ gem env

  . . .

  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin

  . . .
```

So I altered my script like so:

```
GEMS_DIR=${"$( gem env | grep 'EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY' )"#"  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: "}
if [ -d "$GEMS_DIR" ]; then
    export PATH="$GEMS_DIR:$PATH"
fi
```

It works now.

But question is, is there a better way?
Preferably one that wouldn’t rely on the particular formatting of `gem env` output, which I expect might change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gem help env` will tell you what the `gem env` options are. Specifically, it looks like the `gemdir` option is what you want, then you append `/bin`

```
GEMS_DIR=$(gem env gemdir)/bin
```